# Polymer.js and Less.js

Tags: html, less, polymer

Can I use less with polymer?

After  I've written my polymer-element.

```
<polymer-element name="message-tpl" attributes="name avatar">
    <template>
        <link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="less/message.less">
...
```

But stylesheet doesn't work.
Less works if I write `rel="stylesheet"`

Comment: I thought Less had to be compiled to regular CSS before it can be used in the browser.

Comment: One can compile the Less in the browser. http://lesscss.org/#client-side-usage

Comment: This should not work out of the box as the style sheet included in polymer elemt is local to the shadow dom while included less file will sit in the window scope.

Comment: Obviously this question is worth notice. I doubt that web components are not for day-to-day programming unless re-usability of CSS is addressed. (More than using <core-style>)

Answer (score 0):

If you're still interested, I began work on a gulp plugin that converts your *.less files into a Polymer style module. Check it out here: https://github.com/kshep92/gulp-polymer-style

Answer (score -2):

I think this is possible.

1. Extract css to file
2. Compile Less

Just like use bable with Polymer. They use [gulp-crisper](https://github.com/PolymerLabs/crisper) to split code in html, then compile these code.For example

Before

```
<dom-module id="html-echo">
  <style>
    :host {
      display: block;
    }
  </style>
  <template>
  </template>
</dom-module>

<script>
  (function () {
    Polymer({
      is: 'html-echo',
      properties: {
        html: {
          type: String,
          observer: '_htmlChanged'
        }
      },
      _htmlChanged(neo) {
        // WARNING: potential XSS vulnerability if `html` comes from an untrusted source
        this.innerHTML = neo;
      }
    });
  })();
</script>
```

After, there is tow file: `html-echo.html`

```
<html><head></head><body><dom-module id="html-echo">
  <style>
    :host {
      display: block;
    }
  </style>
  <template>
  </template>
</dom-module>

<script src="html-echo.js"></script></body></html>
```

and `html-echo.js`

```
'use strict';

(function () {
  Polymer({
    is: 'html-echo',
    properties: {
      html: {
        type: String,
        observer: '_htmlChanged'
      }
    },
    _htmlChanged: function _htmlChanged(neo) {
      // WARNING: potential XSS vulnerability if `html` comes from an untrusted source
      this.innerHTML = neo;
    }
  });
})();
```

I think this is how less will work with polymer,because polymer need to parse css,there is no way to use less in browser compile(if you don't want to custom shadow element) and less need to support Polymer's style syntax, at least no error report.

Also, I'd like to see if polymer's [css parser](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/blob/master/src/lib/css-parse.html) support less syntax. :P